# How can we get rid of import syntax error in IntelliJ IDEA for Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, syntax

This code is a basic input/output function in Kotlin. But I am facing an issue with syntax even though it is right.

[image]

Comment: Hello Viswa, welcome to Stack Overflow; it's very hard to tell what your problem is, by just looking at an IMAGE of your source code... please provide a minimum reproducible example of what you are trying to do, what you've tried, etc. If you have doubts, [here's the official Stack Overflow documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) about this.

Comment: Do you use a multiplatform project? Can you attach a link to your project?

Comment: Make sure you tell IntelliJ which JDK your project is using.  I'd also recommend the Kotlin plugin for IntelliJ.  I'm writing Kotlin using IntelliJ 2020.3; it works just fine.  It's a problem in your local project setup.

Comment: The Kotlin syntax isn't your problem; it looks like it would compile fine.  (I can't tell for sure because [you've posted an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/10134209), so I can't copy and paste the code.)  The real problem is how the project has been set up: the red `java` indicates that the Java stdlib isn't available.  Depending how you're trying to build it, it could be a problem with the build.gradle or pom.xml file, or with the project settings or JDK settings in your IDE.

Comment: Hey, thanks for ur reply, As you can see there are red marks on code which means to say it's an error code in intellij IDE. Here i am trying to give input using import and scanner statement but unlike java syntax, it is bit different so i made sure it is in kotlin format but still i am getting error. please let me know if u got what i am asking.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the mistake here. first of i wanted to take an input an integer type and also a string type which must be provided by the user. so i tried to use scanner instead we could have used val a: Int =readLine()!!.toInt() for integer type. and val b:string=readLine()!! for string type.